# How can I display a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a flutter app but I'm not sure how to display my list along with other elements.

I'll start with my code

```
class showVehicle extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<Vehicle> vehicle;

  showVehicle({Key key, this.vehicle}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: FutureBuilder<Vehicle>(
                  future: vehicle,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                      case ConnectionState.none:
                        return Text('none');
                      case ConnectionState.waiting:
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      case ConnectionState.active:
                        return Text('');
                      case ConnectionState.done:
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text(
                            '${snapshot.error}',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return InkWell(
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Stack(children: <Widget>[
                                  FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                                    placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                                    image:
                                    '${snapshot.data.defImage}',
                                    height: 250,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                    margin:
                                    EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0),
                                    //width: 250,
                                    height: 250,
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                        colors: <Color>[
                                          Colors.black.withAlpha(0),
                                          Colors.black12,
                                          Colors.black87
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Text(
                                      '${snapshot.data.brand} ${snapshot.data.model}',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                                    ),
  
                                  )
                                ])
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                    }
                  }),
            )
        )
    );
  }

}
```

Where I'm lost is, snapshot.data.fields is a List of fields. I don't know how to loop through this list to display each field.

Each field item has a label and a value.

Can someone show me how I can add that to the bottom of this widget with the existing elements already? My issue is more on flutter, if you can get me pointed in the right direction, then I think I can finish it.

EDIT: I'm adding the futures for the vehicle and fields so you can see the structure

```
Future<Vehicle> fetchVehicle(String id) async {
  final response = await http.get(globals.urlPath + 'vehicles/'+id+'/json/');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON.
    return Vehicle.fromJson(convert.jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}

class Vehicle {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String defImage;
  final String brand;
  final String model;
  final List<Fields> fields;

  Vehicle({this.id, this.title, this.url, this.defImage, this.brand, this.model, this.fields});

  factory Vehicle.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    List<Fields> tempFields = [];
    if(json['[fields]'] != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < json['[fields]'].length; i++) {
        //print("Image: " + i.toString() + " of " + json['images'].length.toString());
        Fields field = Fields.fromJson(json['fields'][i]);
        tempFields.add(field);
      }
    }

    //"Vehicle Type"
    var brand = "";
    var model = "";

    if (json['content'] != null && json['content']['[fields]'] != null){ // we have our fields
      json['content']['[fields]'].forEach((field) {
        Map<String, dynamic> params = field;
        if(field['[label]'] == "Brand"){
          //assign this to something
          brand = field['[fieldFormattedVal]'];
        }
        if(field['[label]'] == "Model"){
          //assign this to something
          model = field['[fieldFormattedVal]'];
        }
       });
    }

    return Vehicle(
      id: json['id'] ?? json['dataObj']['id'],
      title: json['[title]'] ?? json['content']['[fields]'][0]['[fieldFormattedVal]'] ?? '',
      url: json['[url]'] ?? '',
      defImage: json['[fileName]'] ?? json['content']['[images]'][0]['[fileName]'] ?? '',
      brand: brand ?? '',
      model: model ?? '',
      fields: tempFields, //field.fromJson(json['[fields]']) ?? '',
    );
  }
}

class Fields {
  final String conditions;
  final String label;
  final String name;
  final String rawval;
  final String val;

  Fields({this.conditions, this.label, this.name, this.rawval, this.val});

  factory Fields.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Fields(
      conditions: json['conditions'] ?? '',
      label: json['label'] ?? '',
      name: json['name'] ?? '',
      rawval: json['fieldRawVal'] ?? '',
      val: json['fieldFormattedVal'] ?? '',

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add some sample data and the ui that you are expecting to render on the screen.

Comment: I just added more code, I'm new enough to flutter that I'm not sure what you mean by the UI, unless you're just talking about a mock up. The structure is, snapshot.data.fields contains a list object of fields. I'm just specifically not sure how to start looping through that list object of fields for display, any display really.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `ListView.builder` method. You will obviously need the whole `List` for that. So how would you obtain it? Get it through a function that returns `Future <List<Vehicle>>`. Also take a look at the [online docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html).

and in your build method include:

```
List<Vehicle> YourLocalList=[];

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final Future<List<Vehicle>> future = //get in from your function
   return FutureBuilder(future: future, builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      
      print('${snapshot.data}'); //your list

      if(snapshot.hasData&&snapshot.data.length>=1) {
        YourLocalList = snapshot.data;
      
        return ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            itemCount: (YourLocalList.length),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                  child: _taskWidget(index));
            });
      }
  }
```

Modify the `Widget _taskWidget () {/*...*/}` for each entry. (your list UI)

Answer (score 0):

```
case ConnectionState.active:
    return Text(snapshot.data[title]);    // you can reach any field
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27887475)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Kevin What link?